# Is there a financial service that publicly exposes transaction history?

Tags: transactions, finance

This may not be an appropriate question for SO. I don't see a more suitable place for it.

Is there a service, either a (online) bank account, a syndication, or some trusted 3rd party, that would expose the purchase history of a credit card or a bank account (or something that I can pay money out of) publicly and credibly? If I buy a Kindle on Amazon and I'd like someone to be sure that I did, I'd send them a link to this service certifying that I did indeed purchase $130 worth of goods from Amazon.

This would be similar to the effect of adding an account to Paypal, or Google Checkout, or Amazon Payment that has read-only access and could not have its password changed. Is anything like this possible?

Comment: Probably better suited for money.stackexchange.com